# ERROR: attribute verification of </opt/csw/bin/csslint-0.6> failed when install CSWlibcroco for ImageMagick 7 on solaris 11.1

Tags: software-installation, solaris

I got problem with proxy so I must install manually
I am installing ImageMagick 7 on solaris 11.1 and I got stuck with CSWlibcroco

```
pkgadd -d libcroco-0.6.2\,REV\=2009.10.09-SunOS5.8-sparc-CSW.pkg
```

I got this:

```
The following packages are available:
  1  CSWlibcroco     libcroco - A CSS parsing and manipulation toolkit
                     (sparc) 0.6.2,REV=2009.10.09

Select package(s) you wish to process (or 'all' to process
all packages). (default: all) [?,??,q]: 

Processing package instance <CSWlibcroco> from </app/ftl/pkg/libcroco-0.6.2,REV=2009.10.09-SunOS5.8-sparc-CSW.pkg>

libcroco - A CSS parsing and manipulation toolkit(sparc) 0.6.2,REV=2009.10.09
Please see /opt/csw/share/doc/libcroco/license for license information.
## Processing package information.
## Processing system information.
   2 package pathnames are already properly installed.
## Verifying package dependencies.
## Verifying disk space requirements.
## Checking for conflicts with packages already installed.
## Checking for setuid/setgid programs.

Installing libcroco - A CSS parsing and manipulation toolkit as <CSWlibcroco>

## Installing part 1 of 1.
/opt/csw/bin/croco-0.6-config
/opt/csw/bin/sparcv8/csslint-0.6
/opt/csw/bin/sparcv9/croco-0.6-config
/opt/csw/bin/sparcv9/csslint-0.6
/opt/csw/include/libcroco-0.6/libcroco/cr-additional-sel.h
/opt/csw/include/libcroco-0.6/libcroco/cr-attr-sel.h
/opt/csw/include/libcroco-0.6/libcroco/cr-cascade.h
/opt/csw/include/libcroco-0.6/libcroco/cr-declaration.h
/opt/csw/include/libcroco-0.6/libcroco/cr-doc-handler.h
/opt/csw/include/libcroco-0.6/libcroco/cr-enc-handler.h
/opt/csw/include/libcroco-0.6/libcroco/cr-fonts.h
/opt/csw/include/libcroco-0.6/libcroco/cr-input.h
/opt/csw/include/libcroco-0.6/libcroco/cr-num.h
/opt/csw/include/libcroco-0.6/libcroco/cr-om-parser.h
/opt/csw/include/libcroco-0.6/libcroco/cr-parser.h
/opt/csw/include/libcroco-0.6/libcroco/cr-parsing-location.h
/opt/csw/include/libcroco-0.6/libcroco/cr-prop-list.h
/opt/csw/include/libcroco-0.6/libcroco/cr-pseudo.h
/opt/csw/include/libcroco-0.6/libcroco/cr-rgb.h
/opt/csw/include/libcroco-0.6/libcroco/cr-sel-eng.h
/opt/csw/include/libcroco-0.6/libcroco/cr-selector.h
/opt/csw/include/libcroco-0.6/libcroco/cr-simple-sel.h
/opt/csw/include/libcroco-0.6/libcroco/cr-statement.h
/opt/csw/include/libcroco-0.6/libcroco/cr-string.h
/opt/csw/include/libcroco-0.6/libcroco/cr-style.h
/opt/csw/include/libcroco-0.6/libcroco/cr-stylesheet.h
/opt/csw/include/libcroco-0.6/libcroco/cr-term.h
/opt/csw/include/libcroco-0.6/libcroco/cr-tknzr.h
/opt/csw/include/libcroco-0.6/libcroco/cr-token.h
/opt/csw/include/libcroco-0.6/libcroco/cr-utils.h
/opt/csw/include/libcroco-0.6/libcroco/libcroco-config.h
/opt/csw/include/libcroco-0.6/libcroco/libcroco.h
/opt/csw/lib/libcroco-0.6.so <symbolic link>
/opt/csw/lib/libcroco-0.6.so.3 <symbolic link>
/opt/csw/lib/libcroco-0.6.so.3.0.1
/opt/csw/lib/pkgconfig/libcroco-0.6.pc
/opt/csw/lib/sparcv9/libcroco-0.6.so <symbolic link>
/opt/csw/lib/sparcv9/libcroco-0.6.so.3 <symbolic link>
/opt/csw/lib/sparcv9/libcroco-0.6.so.3.0.1
/opt/csw/lib/sparcv9/pkgconfig/libcroco-0.6.pc
/opt/csw/share/doc/libcroco/license
[ verifying class <none> ]
/opt/csw/bin/csslint-0.6 <linked pathname>
ERROR: attribute verification of </opt/csw/bin/csslint-0.6> failed
    pathname does not exist
    unable to create link to </opt/csw/bin/isaexec>

Installation of <CSWlibcroco> partially failed.
```

For more log: `pkgparam -v CSWlibcroco` 
Got:

```
CLASSES='none'
BASEDIR='/'
INSTDATE='Apr 16 2020 11:19'
PKGSAV='/var/sadm/pkg/CSWlibcroco/save'
PKGINST='CSWlibcroco'
WORKDIR_FIRSTMOD='../build-isa-sparcv8'
OPENCSW_MODE64='32/64/isaexec'
OPENCSW_REPOSITORY='https://gar.svn.sf.net/svnroot/gar/csw/mgar/pkg/libcroco/trunk@6810'
HOTLINE='http://www.opencsw.org/bugtrack/'
PSTAMP='dam@build8s-20091009152521'
EMAIL='dam@opencsw.org'
VENDOR='http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/libcroco/0.6/ packaged for CSW by Dagobert Michelsen'
CATEGORY='application'
VERSION='0.6.2,REV=2009.10.09'
ARCH='sparc'
NAME='libcroco - A CSS parsing and manipulation toolkit'
PKG='CSWlibcroco'
OAMBASE='/usr/sadm/sysadm'
PATH='/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sadm/install/bin'
TZ='Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh'
LANG='en_US.UTF-8'
LC_ALL=''
LC_MONETARY=''
LC_MESSAGES=''
LC_COLLATE=''
LC_TIME=''
LC_NUMERIC=''
LC_CTYPE=''
```

Comment: Can you check that you have the [CSWisaexec](https://www.opencsw.org/packages/isaexec/) package installed?

Comment: Yes and Here is it `pkgparam -v CSWisaexec` :
`CLASSES='none'
BASEDIR='/'
INSTDATE='Apr 15 2020 08:56'
PKGSAV='/var/sadm/pkg/CSWisaexec/save'
PKGINST='CSWisaexec'
PSTAMP='bender20090326231911'
EMAIL='phil@opencsw.org'
HOTLINE='http://www.opencsw.org/bugtrack/'
VENDOR='http://www.opencsw.org/ packaged for CSW by Philip Brown'
CATEGORY='system'
VERSION='0.2,REV=2009.03.26'
NAME='isaexec - sneaky wrapper around Sun isaexec'
PKG='CSWisaexec'
ARCH='all'
OAMBASE='/usr/sadm/sysadm'
PATH='/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sadm/install/bin'
.....
`

Comment: Ok. I'll try to reproduce this. I've forgotten a lot of what I knew about pkgs.

Comment: I ran to that error when install imageMagick 7 for solaris 11.1. (SunOS 5.11 11.1 sun4v sparc sun4v)

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem is missing file `csslint-0.6` and `isaexec` in `/opt/csw/bin`. 
I found that two files are default on other Solaris.